# C# datetime format change

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert datetime.now format which is **"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"** to US time format i.e. **"mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"**. More over i want the converted format as datetime not in string because the same is being stored in the database and the field in the database is in datetime format so it will not take string.Please suggest....

Comment: Have you tried using `DateTime.Parse()` on the source value?

Answer (score 6):

A `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a format. `DateTime.Now` doesn't have a format, and if you do any kind of conversion, if you've got a `DateTime`, there's no format. The concept of a format only applies when you're converting to or from a string - and `DateTime.Now` is a `DateTime`, not a `string`.

Just insert the value into the database using `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.UtcNow`) and you'll preserve the *data* which is the important part.

You should only perform string conversions when you actually *have* to - at which point you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) and [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) using [custom date/time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). (Use `TryParseExact` for user input; for machine input which really *should* be valid, use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx).)

Note that it's *usually* a good idea to use custom date/time patterns with the invariant culture, or [standard date/time patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) with "real" cultures (e.g. the user's culture).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#GeneralDateShortTime)

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("g",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime usDateTimeFormat = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now , 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
```